# How to change back-ground color of mat-tab when child-component returned tab-id

Tags: angular, angular-material2, ng-class, mat-tab

each tab is child-commponent and this page have editable dataSource.

when someone change form value in child-component, child-component return tab-id to parent-component.

parent-component iterates tab-id for multiple mat-tab. so when recieved tab-id from child-component, I want to change tab back-ground color.

I coded like this. but not work because I don't know how to kick changeTabColor() again when parent-component got tab-id.

parent-component.html

```
<mat-tab-group>
  <mat-tab *ngFor="let tabPageData of tabPageDatas; let index = index" [label]="tabPageData?.tabName" [ngClass]="{'positive': changeTabColor(tabPageData?.tabCode), 'negative': !changeTabColor(tabPageData?.tabCode)}">
    <child-component (edited)="edited($event)" [value]="tabPageData"></child-component>
  </mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>
```

parent-component.scss

```
.positive {
  background-color: green;
}

.negative {
  background-color: transparent;
}
```

parent-component.ts

```
editedTabCodeAry = new Array<string>();

edited(tabCode: string) {
  this.editedTabCodeAry.push(tabCode);
}

changeTabColor(tabCode: string) {
  return this.editedTabCodeAry.indexOf(tabCode) >= 0;
}
```

child-component.ts

```
  @Output()
  edited = new EventEmitter<string>();

  // this method run when form in tab edited
  dataUpdate(copy: Data) {
    // run data update method here
    // return edited tabCode
    this.edited.emit(this.value.tabCode);
  }
```

Comment: you can simply call the changeTabColor function from the edited function maybe it works

Comment: but changeTabColor function's parameter tabCode is for iterated data in html.

Comment: okay got it i am writing a ans pls check after few mins

Answer (score 1):

you can try like this

**parent html**

```
 <mat-tab-group>
   <mat-tab *ngFor="let tabPageData of tabPageDatas; let index = index" 
    [label]="tabPageData?.tabName" [ngClass]="{ classFlag[index] === true ? 'positive' : 'negative': 
       !changeTabColor(tabPageData?.tabCode)}">
         <child-component (edited)="edited($event)" [value]="tabPageData" [index]="index"></child- 
         component>
   </mat-tab>
 </mat-tab-group>
```

**child ts**

```
  @Output()
  edited = new EventEmitter<string>();
  @Input() index: number = null;
  // this method run when form in tab edited
 dataUpdate(copy: Data) {
   // run data update method here
   // return edited tabCode
  this.edited.emit({tabcode: this.value.tabCode, index: this.index});
 }
```

**parent ts**

```
  classFlag: any = [];
  functionForSettingADefaultClassFlagValue() {
  // in this function we are setting the default value of classFlag so i iterate loop with the length of tabPageDatas
      for (let i =0; i < tabPageDatas.length; i++) {
       this.classFlag[i] = false
      }
  }

  edited(data: any) {
       this.editedTabCodeAry.push(tabCode);
       this.changeTabColor(data);
  }

  changeTabColor(data) {
   if (this.editedTabCodeAry.indexOf(data.tabCode) >= 0) {
     this.classFlag[index] = true;
   } else {
     this.classFlag[index] = false;
   }
  }
```

i hope it helps you out.

Comment: thank you for your advice.  I changed html a little. because it was error. so I changed like this. [ngClass]="{ 'positive': classFlg[index] === true, 'negative': classFlg[index] === false}". but still tab-color not change. ;_;

Comment: if you implement the css property statically then it is working as expected ?

Comment: How to implement css property statically?   I have no specific image. Could you give me some example please?

Comment: statically means like this  [ngClass]="'positive'". Is it change the color of your element?

Comment: I changed like this  [ngClass]="'positive'". but tab backgrorund-color doesn't change. ;_;

Comment: so that means there are some issues with css you can also put the log on our changeTabColor and see if our logic is working as expected or not.

Comment: and if my answer help you please accept my answer  :)

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by different approach.
I implements Renderer2 and Document

```
constructor(@Inject(DOCUMENT) private document: Document,private renderer: Renderer2)
```

in edited method

```
this.renderer.addClass(this.document.getElementById(`mat-tab-label-0-${data.index}`), 'positive');
```

that's all